# Jsoup body fragment throws out HTML tags

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I have a bit of a dilemma.  I need to parse a chunk of HTML through JSoup, that chunk is later passed on to another class that handles the jsoup elements.  Unfortunately when I pass a chunk into Jsoup that represents a part of a table, for some odd reason jsoup just throws out all of the html and delivers me nothing, but the text.  Here is an example:

```
<tr>
   <td>Declared</td>
   <td>Other Supported Languages</td>
   <td>/ATP_ETK_89078_1006/atp_etk_89078_1006_p4/nonshared/E-trak_API_Build/obfuscated/vna.dll</td>
   <td align="right">1519616</td>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td>COM DEV</td>
   <td>Unspecified</td>
   <td>License for COM DEV</td>
   <td>Component (Dynamic Library)</td>
   <td>100%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td valign="top"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Declared</td>
   <td>Other Supported Languages</td>
   <td>/ATP_ETK_89078_1006/atp_etk_89078_1006_p4/nonshared/E-trak_API_Build/obfuscated/vna.dll</td>
   <td align="right">1519616</td>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td align="right"></td>
   <td>COM DEV</td>
   <td>Unspecified</td>
   <td>License for COM DEV</td>
   <td>Component (Dynamic Library)</td>
   <td>100%</td>
   <td style="text-align: center;"></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td valign="top"></td>
</tr>
```

This is the fragment and as you can see it just represents two rows from a table.

However the Jsoup Doc produces the following:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body> 
   Declared Other Supported Languages /ATP_ETK_89078_1006/atp_etk_89078_1006_p4/nonshared/E-trak_API_Build/obfuscated/vna.dll 1519616   COM DEV Unspecified License for COM DEV Component (Dynamic Library) 100%     
   Declared Other Supported Languages /ATP_ETK_89078_1006/atp_etk_89078_1006_p4/nonshared/E-trak_API_Build/obfuscated/vna.dll 1519616   COM DEV Unspecified License for COM DEV Component (Dynamic Library) 100%           
   </body>
</html>
```

Now if the original headers of the table were there including the table open/close headers it seems to work, but that defeats the entire purpose of this fragment parsing as the HTML docs can get quite huge.

ANY HELP would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with **JSoup 1.7.1** --> same problem.

I guess, the only way is to wrap your fragment into a `table`-tag.

```
String html = ... // your html
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
// doesn't work as you said


String html = ... // your html
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<table>" + html + "</table>");
// works
```

Don't know how you use Jsoup in your case, but maybe you can do somethink like this:

```
public String doSomethingWithFragment(String html)
{
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<table>" + html + "</table>");
    Elements fragment = doc.select("tbody > *");

    // Do something with 'fragment' here ...
}
```

In this example `fragment` contains exactly the HTML as you posted above and you can do further things with it.

I know its a realy strange workaround - adding things and remove it in the next step. But however ... it works *(i hope)* :-) ...